# R Specify colors in sankeyNetwork

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js

I am trying to create a Sankey diagram using the `networkD3` package in R, particularly the `sankeyNetwork` function. I am trying to replicate the Sankey Diagram from Lawrence Livermore National Lab:

[image]

So far I have been able to use the following code to get close:

Data:

```r
energy <- structure(list(nodes = structure(list(name = structure(c(15L, 
 11L, 8L, 17L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 12L, 4L, 14L, 3L, 9L, 16L, 13L, 
 6L, 5L), .Label = c("Biomass", "Coal", "Commericial", "Electricity", 
"Energy Services", "Exports", "Geothermal", "Hydro", "Industrial", 
"Natural Gas", "Nuclear", "Petroleum", "Rejected Energy", "Residential", 
"Solar", "Transportation", "Wind"), class = "factor")), .Names = "name",                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L)), links = structure(list(source = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L), target = c(9L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 
 10L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
 13L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 
 16L, 14L, 16L, 14L, 16L, 14L, 16L), value = c(0.25, 0.28, 8.34, 
 2.38, 0.01, 1.81, 0.16, 0.04, 0.02, 9.99, 4.75, 3.3, 9.36, 0.92, 
 14.3, 1.41, 0.52, 0.45, 0.13, 2.28, 1.35, 0.28, 0.98, 0.56, 8.2, 
 25.4, 4.78, 4.63, 3.27, 0.03, 25.4, 0.08, 3.95, 7.33, 3.05, 5.66, 
 4.91, 19.6, 21.9, 5.81), energy_type = structure(c(12L, 12L, 
 9L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 
 5L, 11L, 4L, 11L, 4L, 11L, 4L, 11L, 4L), .Label = c("Biomass", 
"Coal", "Electricity", "Energy Services", "Exports", "Geothermal", 
"Hydro", "Natural", "Nuclear", "Petroleum", "Rejected Energy", 
"Solar", "Wind"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("source", "target", 
"value", "energy_type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))), .Names = c("nodes", "links"))
```

And the actual code is:

```
library(networkD3)

sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              units = "Quads", LinkGroup = "energy_type", colourScale = JS(
                'd3.scale.ordinal()  
                   .domain(["Solar","Nuclear","Hydro","Wind","Geothermal","Natural Gas","Coal","Biomass","Petroleum","Electricity","Residential","Commericial","Industrial","Transportation","Rejected Energy","Exports","Energy Services"])
                   .range(["#FFFF00","#FF0000","#0000FF","#800080","#A52A2A","#00FFFF","#000000","#00FF00","#008000","#FFA500","#FAAFBE","#FAAFBE","#FAAFBE","#FAAFBE","#C0C0C0","#FFA500","#808080"])'
              ), fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 75, iterations = 100)
```

My problem is that I cannot get the colors to match up right. I want to specify my own colors. I am a novice at D3, so that might be my problem. I think that my problem is in the `d3.scale.ordinal()` part of the code, so I have broken it out to hopefully make it easier to find my error. But I think I am trying to tell the function to color the "Natural Gas" box a cyan (#00FFFF) color, but it is showing up yellow. Also the "Rejected Energy" and "Energy Services" colors are also off.

Comment: your `energy$nodes` do not match those in `energy$links$energy_type`. try running this `setdiff(energy$links$energy_type, energy$nodes$name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps.  I will try to comment inline.  As chinsoon12 suggests, it appears your nodes don't quite match.  Running his code, we see.

```
> setdiff(energy$links$energy_type, energy$nodes$name)
[1] "Natural"
```

This tells us that `"Natural"` was used in your data for links while `"Natural Gas"` was used in your nodes.  I often find it helpful to use a `data.frame` to help me identify problems in my color scale.

```
energy <- structure(list(nodes = structure(list(name = structure(c(15L, 
     11L, 8L, 17L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 12L, 4L, 14L, 3L, 9L, 16L, 13L, 
     6L, 5L), .Label = c("Biomass", "Coal", "Commericial", "Electricity", 
    "Energy Services", "Exports", "Geothermal", "Hydro", "Industrial", 
    "Natural Gas", "Nuclear", "Petroleum", "Rejected Energy", "Residential", 
    "Solar", "Transportation", "Wind"), class = "factor")), .Names = "name",                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -17L)), links = structure(list(source = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
     3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
     8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
     12L, 12L, 13L, 13L), target = c(9L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 
     10L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
     13L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 
     16L, 14L, 16L, 14L, 16L, 14L, 16L), value = c(0.25, 0.28, 8.34, 
     2.38, 0.01, 1.81, 0.16, 0.04, 0.02, 9.99, 4.75, 3.3, 9.36, 0.92, 
     14.3, 1.41, 0.52, 0.45, 0.13, 2.28, 1.35, 0.28, 0.98, 0.56, 8.2, 
     25.4, 4.78, 4.63, 3.27, 0.03, 25.4, 0.08, 3.95, 7.33, 3.05, 5.66, 
     4.91, 19.6, 21.9, 5.81), energy_type = structure(c(12L, 12L, 
     9L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 
     5L, 11L, 4L, 11L, 4L, 11L, 4L, 11L, 4L), .Label = c("Biomass", 
    "Coal", "Electricity", "Energy Services", "Exports", "Geothermal", 
    "Hydro", "Natural", "Nuclear", "Petroleum", "Rejected Energy", 
    "Solar", "Wind"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("source", "target", 
    "value", "energy_type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -40L))), .Names = c("nodes", "links")) 

library(networkD3)

sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = "source",
         Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
         units = "Quads", LinkGroup = 'energy_type', colourScale = JS(

           'd3.scaleOrdinal()  
    .domain(["Solar","Nuclear","Hydro","Wind","Geothermal","Natural Gas","Coal","Biomass","Petroleum","Electricity","Residential","Commericial","Industrial","Transportation","Rejected Energy","Exports","Energy Services"])
    .range(["#FFFF00","#FF0000","#0000FF","#800080","#A52A2A","#00FFFF","#000000","#00FF00","#008000","#FFA500","#FAAFBE","#FAAFBE","#FAAFBE","#FAAFBE","#C0C0C0","#FFA500","#808080"])'

         ), 
fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 75, iterations = 100)

# putting in a data.frame might help see problems
color_scale <- data.frame(
  range = c("#FFFF00","#FF0000","#0000FF","#800080","#A52A2A","#00FFFF","#000000","#00FF00","#008000","#FFA500","#FAAFBE","#FAAFBE","#FAAFBE","#FAAFBE","#C0C0C0","#FFA500","#808080"),
  domain = c("Solar","Nuclear","Hydro","Wind","Geothermal","Natural Gas","Coal","Biomass","Petroleum","Electricity","Residential","Commericial","Industrial","Transportation","Rejected Energy","Exports","Energy Services"),
  nodes = energy$nodes,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# once corrected color_scale can be used like this
sankeyNetwork(
  Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = "source",
  Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
  units = "Quads", LinkGroup = 'energy_type', colourScale = JS(
sprintf(
'd3.scaleOrdinal()  
  .domain(%s)
  .range(%s)
',
jsonlite::toJSON(color_scale$domain),
jsonlite::toJSON(color_scale$range)
   )
  ), 
  fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 75, iterations = 100
)

# if we change Natural Gas to Natural then
#   the cyan appears as desired
color_scale[6,2] <- "Natural"
```

[image: sankey diagram screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. You did find an issue with my names (doh!), but even when I fixed it, I kept getting the same issue. I ended up putting an underscore between Natural and Gas (Natural Gas -> Natural_Gas) and that fixed it. When I did that for the two nodes on the far right, it put the right colors in for them too (gray and dark gray)... It seems that the D3 doesn't like the two-word names? I am still not sure. I'd like to not have this workaround if possible.

Comment: names with spaces shouldn't be a problem. I will dig into the code to see what is happening.

Comment: Here are the offending lines [73](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/sankeyNetwork.js#L73) and [81](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/sankeyNetwork.js#L81).  There really is no purpose for the regex that I can see, so I would classify this as a bug.  We are planning to make some major improvements in sankey, and will make sure this gets fixed there.

Comment: Thanks @timelyportfolio I have suggestions for things I'd like to see in sankey if there is an open suggestion box!

Comment: I am trying to recreate this answer, but I get a blank HTML document when I try to do so, has sankeyNetwork changed since this answer was provided? @timelyportfolio

Comment: networkD3 now uses d3v4, so change `d3.scale.ordinal` to `d3.scaleOrdinal`.  will adjust the solution also.

Comment: also, you might be interested in sankeyD3 https://github.com/fbreitwieser/sankeyD3

Answer (score 2):

I also had problems with spaces in the names of nodes. Here there is an example

```
library(networkD3)
Class<-c("Fristående","Nästan_öppet", "Halvöppet", "Slutet")
# Class<-c("Fristående","Nästan öppet", "Halvöppet", "Slutet") #Broken
nClass<-length(Class)
UtMat<-matrix(c(6, 9, 8, 0, 
            0, 9, 18, 3,
            0, 1, 18, 6,
            0, 0, 3, 10), nClass,nClass, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(Class, Class) )

ClassF <- structure(list(nodes = data.frame(name=as.factor(c(Class,Class)), label=c(Class,Class)),
                     links = data.frame(source = rep(c(0:3), each=4), # from
                                        target = rep(c(4:7), 4), # to
                                        value = as.vector(t(UtMat)),
                                        group = as.factor(rep(Class, each=4)))
                      )
                )
sankeyNetwork(Links = ClassF$links, Nodes = ClassF$nodes, 
          Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
          units = "", LinkGroup = 'group', 
          colourScale = JS(
            'd3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(["Fristående","Nästan_öppet","Halvöppet","Slutet"])
            .range(["#EDF8E9","#BAE4B3","#74C476","#238B45"])' 
          ),
          fontFamily = "Arial", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 75)
```

In this example, the classes should be colored from light green to dark green, but if I use the second Class vector (with space), it just mess it up.

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: Answer, as by now, you can't use spaces in the names of the classes. Removing the spaces is a work around to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the problem related to spaces in node names when you want to assign colors manually by not specifying `.domain` in `d3.scaleOrdinal()`. You only have to introduce your colors in `.range` in the same order as your nodes.

For instance, assuming this is the order of your nodes: Fristående, Nästan_öppet, Halvöppet, Slutet, you only need to specify this:

```
'd3.scaleOrdinal()
            .range(["#EDF8E9","#BAE4B3","#74C476","#238B45"])'
```